# How to tie entity recognition to intent prediction?

Tags: rasa-core

I'm having a problem with Rasa_NLU giving me the wrong entity for an intent.  An example is “How do I get to New York?” Where, I tagged the training data to name the entity “city”. In a different intent, it was tagged “destination”.

### intent: check_weather

```
what is the weather in new york?
```

### intent: get_directions

```
how do I get to new york?
```

I have a script that takes action on the intent returned and processes the entities. If I get back the get_directions intent, I’ll look in the json for the destination entity, but it has city instead. Using ner_crf, is there a way to de-emphasize entities in an intent, so that the classifier is biased to those that the intent was trained for? That is, the classifier would be weighted to giving a destination for get_directions, and a city for get_weather?

The typical answer I've found is to add more training examples. I'm up to 60 for each of the two intents I have, and it is still getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, you can only featurize/unfeaturize all entities for a certain intent. I can see that that's not really your use case since both intents require entities -- just different ones. There is currently a [community PR](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/pull/1841) open to add per-intent featurization of specific entities, so it will be available in the future.